# Удаление скриптом лишней информации в копии книги Google Sheets

Tags: google-spreadsheet

Есть такая задача, из таблицы содержащей множество данных и комментарии к ним, нужно сделать таблицу данных по фильтру (инструмент таблиц - не скриптом) и содержащим так же комментарии.

Так как комментарии никаким образом не копируются, у меня складывается вот такой алгоритм,

- копируем книгу с примененным фильтром
- удаляем лишнее)

и сам вопрос - как удалить все данные таблицы кроме нужных + шапка к этим данным, и оставить комментарии?

Comment: Замените данные в ячейках на пустые строки.

Comment: Как определить в какие строки нужно заменить на пустые?